# Upgrading Ghost Broke My Website

Tags: nginx, ghost

My ghost blog was running fine and i've just tried to upgrade it using the guide posted [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-digitalocean-ghost-application). I am using Digital Ocean as the web host by the way.

After upgrade it's showing some problems, I've looked at the error log and it's showing a bunch of errors like this:

```
2015/09/07 13:22:50 [error] 3987#0: *23 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: (IP HIDDEN), server: my-ghost-blog.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:2368/favicon.ico", host: "HOST HIDDEN", referrer: "http://URL HIDDEN/"
```

I've removed IPs and what not

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I recently upgraded and encountered some errors, finally got them resolved.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody nope, I just migrated to wordpress in the end

Comment: That's too bad @Callum. After some struggles I was able to get it working. I did a write-up here - http://brettdewoody.com/updating-ghost-on-digital-ocean-ubuntu/

Comment: just troubleshooting the same issue. resolution would be appreciated

Comment: hey @BrettDeWoody thanks for your post, I think this line fixed my issue "chown -R ghost:ghost ghost/*" :)

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody has answered it I might as well post what worked for me. I was able to start the blog manually with *npm start* it was just the *service ghost start* that reported *[OK]* but didn't actually start it.

First I was able to find the error in /var/log/nginx/errors.log

2016/02/08 21:18:27 [error] 601#0: *2086 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: my-ghost-blog.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/favicon.ico", host: "mydomain.com", referrer: "http://example.com/path-to-post/"

I had to recursively change the owner of /ghost directory like this:

```
chown -R ghost:ghost ghost/*
```

I executed it from /var/www

thanks to @BrettDeWoody for his post

Comment: And the moral of the story is we should always check our permissions are right after upgrading any piece of software on linux (probably solves quite a few SO posts...)

Comment: @JamesMurphy unfortunately it is not clear exactly what permissions are needed for this service to work properly. can you elaborate?

Comment: What I mean is that if you install anything on a linux based system you should grant access to the user who's using that application (whether that's specifically the user or a group to which it belongs) as a matter of course.